# What is the main Storyboard called in VLC ios?

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

Im trying to modify and learn from the ios open source code for ios.

Its a mixture of Objective C and Swift.

Is it possible to tell from the repo what the main storyboard is called? Id like to add a login screen that redirects back to the Initial screen but not sure how to get the Storyboard name

Here is the repo

https://github.com/videolan/vlc-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no “main storyboard”.

The app is created from the app delegate (like all apps were “back in the day”).

https://github.com/videolan/vlc-ios/blob/master/Sources/VLCAppDelegate.m

You can see in the function `applicationDidFinishLaunching` it creates a tabBarController and window and the passes the tab bar controller into a coordinator that will populate it with other view controllers.

This was the norm for all apps once. And is still a perfectly viable option for apps now too.

Comment: Thanks very much. Thats cleared a lot up. Can i programatically redirect back to that tabBarController?

Comment: Sure, you can do anything you want programmatically. It seems to do a lot of setup though so you would have to make sure to set it all up the same way after your login screen.

Comment: Can you link me to an article that programatically changes to a view controller setup the old way as you put it please?

Comment: There isn’t really an article as it’s just a thing you can do. And every app would do it differently. If it was me I would change the app coordinator to present the login screen and then transition to the tab bar controller or something. There are as many ways of doing this as there are iOS apps so there’s not really a set guide for it. Sorry.